# Time-complexity for text analyser code in python

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

```
letterList = ["a", 0, "b", 0, "c", 0, "d", 0, "e", 0, "f", 0, "g", 0, "h", 0, "i", 0,  "j", 0, "k", 0, "l", 0, "m", 0, "n", 0, "o", 0, "p", 0, "q", 0, "r", 0, "s", 0, "t", 0, "u", 0, "v", 0, "w", 0, "x", 0, "y", 0, "z", 0]
letterCount = 0
wordList = [None]
wordCount = 0
Count = 0
wordIndex = [0]
itext = cleaner(raw_input("enter itext please")).split()
print itext
for iword in itext:
    if iword in wordList:
        Count += 1
        for word in wordList:
            if iword == word:
                wordList[wordList.index(word)+1][0] += 1
                wordList[wordList.index(word)+1] += [wordCount]
            else:
                pass
    elif iword not in wordList:
        wordList += [iword]
        wordList += [[1, itext.index(iword)]]
    else:
        pass
    wordCount += 1
print wordList
```

The code looks and is messy, because I'm a rank beginner in python as well as in programming.

Can anyone help me to work the time-complexity of the code?

Comment: Sorry for offtop, but why did you put `if, elif, else` if you have only two possible returned values of `in` ?

Comment: perhaps in case the universe changes such that ¬(P ∨ ¬P) ???

Comment: @msw aka `to be or not to be? or neither be nor not be?` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from a difference in formatting, everything after `print itext` can be replaced by:

```
print collections.Counter(itext)
```

This has complexity O(n).

Without Counter, you can better express your algorithm using a dict rather than a list to store the word counts:

```
word_counter = {}
for word in itext:
    if word in word_counter:
        word_counter[word] += 1
    else:
        word_counter[word] = 1
```

A dict is perfect for storing the association between something (here a word) and something else (here a count). A list of alternating pairs of word and count has quite a few disadvantages over a dict, but the killer is that finding a word in the list is O(N) instead of O(1).

Comment: thank you very much @Anonymous . but one more thing, could you please how do you come to O(n), step by step? again I say im a rank beginner, :D

Answer (score 0):

The second loop is useless.
You just need the index of `iword` in `wordlist`.

```
for iword in itext:
    if iword in wordList:
        i = wordList.index(iword)
        wordList[i+1][0] += 1
        wordList[i+1].append(wordCount)
        Count +=1
    else:
        wordList.append(iword)
        wordList.append([1, itext.index(iword)])
    wordCount += 1
print wordList
```

This produces the same output as your code but to be honest it is quite unclear to me if it is really what your expect...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming using loop counts for complexity.

First, we need to find a worst case scenario. The first time through the loop has a complexity of 1, the second time through has a max complexity of 3. During the third time, if the second loop had a complexity of 3, then the third would also have a max complexity of 3, giving a total complexity of 7. If you give the second a complexity of 1, you can give the third a max complexity of 5, but that still gives you a total complexity of 7. However, at this point it gets weird. The max complexity for the fourth time through is if you have a complexity of 1, 1, 5, and 5, for a total of 12. 5 has 1, 1, 1, 7, and 7 = 17. 6 has 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, and 7 = 24. 1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 9, 9 = 31. 1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 9, 9, 9 = 40. Finding a generic worst case scenario in that is really kinda hard, but I would say the worst case scenario is when the first half (whether you use the floor or ceiling of half doesn't matter) of the string is made up of new words, and the remaining part of the string is made of up the last new word added. "red green blue yellow yellow yellow yellow" is an example of a worst case scenario for 7 words. Putting that into mathematical terms looks a little like this:

```
O(ceiling(n/2) + floor(n/2)*(ceiling(n/2)*2+1))
```

or, the python to figure out the complexity given a list size:

```
from __future__ import division
import math
def complexity(n):
    return math.ceil(n/2) + math.floor(n/2)*(math.ceil(n/2)*2+1)
```

That said, your algorithm is horrendous and you should really replace it with one of the ones given by the other answers.